# Conditionally assign values from another column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to change zero values in a dataframe for the value found in the last column for each row. I can solve this using a for in the columns or the rows, but it didnt seem too pythonic to me.

In short, I have a dataframe like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 nonzero 
1    2    0    10
1    0    3    20
```

and I'd like to do an operation like

```
df[df==0] = df.nonzero
```

so I'd get

```
col1 col2 col3 nonzero 
   1    2   10 10
   1   20    3 20
```

This however does not work, as [df==0] is a DataFrame itself with True/False values. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `apply` method, loop through rows of the data frame and replace zeros with the last element of the row:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.where(row != 0, row.iat[-1]), axis=1)
```

[image]

You can also modify the data frame in place:

```
df[df == 0] = (df == 0).mul(df.nonzero, axis=0)
```

Which yields `df` as the same result above. In this method, `(df == 0).mul(df.nonzero, axis=0)` creates a data frame with zeros entries replaced by the values in the nonzero column and other entries zero; Combined with boolean indexing and assignment, you can conditionally modify the zero entries in the original data frame:

```
(df == 0).mul(df.nonzero, axis=0)
```

[image]

Comment: The df==0.mul solution worked just fine, but the apply method gave me the error 'No axis named 1 for object type class <Series>  occurred at index col1'

Comment: You may have placed the `axis` parameter not correctly, notice it's a parameter of `apply` method, instead of `where`, if `df` is a data frame, not a Series object.